# IEnumerable conversion (?) for model to parameter needed?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a view where I'm going to list a checkbox-list (helper), and I'm not sure howto call that, since it always says my "type" is wrong.

I'm trying to call:

```
public static string CheckBoxList(this HtmlHelper htmlhelper, IEnumerable<string> values, IEnumerable<string> labels, string name)
    {
        return CheckBoxList(htmlhelper, values, labels, name, ((IDictionary<string, object>) null));
    }
```

And view looks like:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/AdminSite.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<BookingSystem.MVC.ViewModels.TestViewModel>" %>
```

Test

```
<h2>Test</h2>

<table>  
<%= Html.CheckBoxList((IEnumerable<string>)Model.Usergroups, (IEnumerable<string>)Model.Usergroups, "asdf")  %>

<% foreach (var item in Model.Usergroups) { %>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <%= item.UsergroupName %>
        </td>
    </tr>
<% } %>
</table>

<p>
    <%= Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create") %>
</p>
```

How can I get this to work, I want my checkbox-list helper to work from different views, so I guess I have to convert the parameters somehow?

/M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting the name of a type in parentheses is called a cast. It doesn't actually "convert" an object into another type. Rather, it switches off type checking at compile time. So if it works at compile time, that proves very little.

In the example code you've posted, there's no good reason to uses casts anywhere. (In particular, you never need to cast `null` to anything.)

You need to get an `IEnumerable<string>` from some part of your model? The right way to do that will depend on the structure of your model.

The easiest way to do it in C# 3.0 is to call the `Select` extension method on an `IEnumerable` of some type:

```
var strings = Model.Usergroups.Select(ug => ug.UsergroupName);
```

Hey presto.

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem. I need to pass a IEnumerable in parameter. And I try to get values of this with a foreach in the controller. But it seems empty... Whereas is not. Why ?